# Multiple MySQL instances one server through systemd - cannot connect client

Tags: systemd, multiple-instances, mysql8

I am using MySQL 8.0.33

Following [the official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-systemd.html), I set up multiple instances of mysql using systemd. My cnf file is below. I am able to get all the instances up and running at the same time, systemctl status shows each of them with its correct sock file per my configuration, but I am unable to connect a client to any but the initial, default instance.

When I first install mysql [per the instructions here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/), I enter the root password.

When I initially start each additional instance, the error.log reports that a root user was created with an empty password.

After spinning up the servers (sudo systemctl start mysql@seeds; sudo systemctl start mysql@manofmystery), I try to connect with the client:

```
mysql --host=localhost --port=3307(or 3308) -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3307 -u root
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

mysql --host=localhost --port=3307 -u root -p
Enter password: (ENTER for empty password)
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3307 -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

If I enter the root password I made for the initial instance, I am able to connect and get the mysql> prompt, but when I type "status", it tells me I am connected with that sock file, NOT the one for port 3307. So I can connect to the initial instance as root, but not to any of the others.

I have tried "skip-grant-tables" in the cnf file but it made no difference.

My /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqlx          = 0

[mysqld@seeds]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld-seeds/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld-seeds/mysqld.sock
port            = 3307
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql-seeds
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/seeds.error.log
mysqlx          = 0

[mysqld@manofmystery]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld-manofmystery/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld-manofmystery/mysqld.sock
port            = 3308
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql-manofmystery
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/manofmystery.error.log
mysqlx          = 0
```

Again, I have verified that all three instances are running, have logs and data dirs. I just cannot connect to the ones on ports 3307 and 3308.

Comment: Consider spin up the servers (sudo systemctl start mysqld@seeds; sudo systemctl start mysqld@manofmystery), to start the 'dameon' for each server.  Welcome to SF.